# How can I remove main-page scrolling and just allow iframe scrolling?

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to create a full-screen preview like this [Themeforest](http://themeforest.net/item/smartstart-responsive-html5-template/full_screen_preview/1674915) link has,
What I have achieved is [This page](http://design-blog.co.cc/demo/index.php), i have just one problem left, which is the *double scrolling*, as you see in themeforest link, it is only one vertical scrollbar that is of preview iframe, but in my case, i am still getting two scrollbars, one of main page and one of iframe, i just want to have only iframe bar there. How can i get this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this to css `body, html{ overflow: hidden }`

Comment: Thanks a lot...I have tried so many things with `margin` `padding` and all but forget this one...thank you